# Reading a number value from a form javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to retrieve a number from a from in my HTML, but the javascript doesn't read the value as I would expect it to.

The code I'm using is

```
<input type="number" id="itemsize" name='itemsize' onChange="calculateTotal()"/>
```

Note that calculateTotal successfully calls getSizePrice, but doesn't read it as a number

```
function getSizePrice()
{
    var sizePrice=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["orderform"];
    sizePrice = theForm.elements["itemsize"];
    return sizePrice;

}
```

Comment: Lots of things missing here but once you have the element you will want to get the value of it using sizePrice.value;

Comment: In the future, it will help you to get an answer quicker if you make a jsfiddle.

Comment: I also agree with @SteveWellens using a website like https://jsfiddle.net/ helps you and others with theses types of issues

Comment: You are returning the DOM element not the actual value, `theForm.elements["itemsize"].value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should it be

sizePrice = parseFloat(theForm.elements["itemsize"].value);

Answer (score 0):

the input is passing in a text value  - you will need to parse it to get a number. the following will convert the input value to a number. Also I am unfamiliar with this code structure - are you actually getting the value from the input? should you be using ...theForm.elements["itemsize"].value...

```
sizePrice = parseInt(theForm.elements["itemsize"]);
```

Comment: Or use parseFloat if it is not an integer.

Comment: You are using parseInt on a DOM element not the actual value

Comment: When I made the adjustment, the final result showed up as NaN